# Navigation Property can be a Generic type?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

I have a Navigation Property `public virtual IUser<int> CreateBy { get; set; }`

When I try to add a migration `Add-Migration InitialMigration`, the following error occurs:

> The navigation property 'CreateBy' is not a declared property on type 'Passo'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

My type `Passo`

```
public class Passo : EntityNome, IAuditable
{
    public virtual int? Ordem { get; set; }
    public virtual Passo ProximoPasso { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Responsaveis { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<CheckListItemTemplate> CheckListItens { get; protected set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreateAt { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual IUser<int> CreateBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UpdateAt { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IUser<int> UpdateBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IUser is a collection of int ?   You cant navigate to primitives.

It needs to be a collection of or reference to a Table declared in the context.

```
public DbSet<int> Integers { get; set; }// you cant declare table of integers ???
```

// futhermore EF needs public get/set and this will be ignored
   public virtual ICollection Responsaveis { get; protected set; }

please see navigation concept 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx